# Pushforward of equivariant sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, equivariant-maps

I work over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.  Let $G$ be an algebraic group, $X,Y$ varieties with $G$-actions, and $\phi:X\to Y$ a $G$-equivariant morphism.  Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a quasi-coherent $G$-equivariant sheaf of $X$.  I want to show that $\phi_*\mathcal{F}$ has the natural structure of a $G$-equivariant sheaf.

Write $a_X:G\times X\to X$ and $a_Y:G\times Y\to Y$ for the action morphisms and $p_X:G\times X\to X$, $p_Y:G\times Y\to Y$ for the projections.  Then since $\mathcal{F}$ is equivariant it is equipped with an isomorphism of sheaves $\varphi:a_X^*\mathcal{F}\to p_X^*\mathcal{F}$.  Pushing this isomorphism forward along $(\text{id}_G\times\phi)$, we obtain an isomorphism of sheaves
$$
(\text{id}_G\times\phi)a_X^*\mathcal{F}\cong (\text{id}_G\times\phi)p_X^*\mathcal{F}
$$
My idea for obtaining an equivariant structure is to use a base change theorem applied to the squares
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
G\times X @>{\text{id}_G\times\phi}>> G\times Y\\
@VVV @VVV\\
X @>{\phi}>> Y
\end{CD}
where the downward arrows are either $a_X,a_Y$ or $p_X,p_Y$.  I think flat base change should apply here if the action morphisms and projection morphisms are flat.  Of course the projection morphisms are flat, although I don't know if the action morphisms are flat but it seems like they should be.  Is this correct?  Does anyone have a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean to show that the canonical map $$ a_{Y}^{\ast}(\phi_{\ast}\mathcal{F}) \to (\mathrm{id}_{G} \times \phi)_{\ast}a_{X}^{\ast}\mathcal{F} $$ is an isomorphism right? I think there is a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
G\times X @>{\alpha}>> G\times X\\
@V{a_{X}}VV @VV{p_{X}}V\\
X @>>{\mathrm{id}_{X}}> X
\end{CD}
where $\alpha : G \times X \to G \times X$ sends $(g,x) \mapsto (g,gx)$. This map $\alpha$ is an isomorphism because the map $(g,x) \mapsto (g,g^{-1}x)$ is its inverse. Thus $a_{X}$ and $p_{X}$ have the same properties.